# Need help making a simple MotionBlur/Trail effect in swing

Tags: java

I currently have nothing to do so I just wanted to create a simple firework-program. It works fine but now I want to add a little MotionBlur-Trail to the starterParticle (Rocket) and I can't figure out a way to do this.

I think I need a function that calculates the trail based on the speed of the rocket. The function needs to calculate how much particles there need to be and which opacity and coordinates they have.

so this is my try (located in the Firework class):

```java
public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for(Sparkle s : sparkles) {
            s.draw(g);
        }
        if(!exploded) {
            for(int alpha = 255, i = 0; alpha >= 5; alpha-=starterSparkle.ySpeed*10, i++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(starterSparkle.myColor.getRed(), starterSparkle.myColor.getGreen(), 
                    starterSparkle.myColor.getBlue(), alpha));
                g.fillRect((int) starterSparkle.x, (int) (starterSparkle.y + (starterSparkle.ySpeed * i)), 
                    (int) this.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS, (int) this.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS);
            }
        }
    }
```

Firework class:

```java
package Firework;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Firework {

    public Window myPanel;
    public ArrayList<Sparkle> sparkles;
    public Sparkle starterSparkle;
    public boolean exploded;
    public boolean expired;
    public Random rand = new Random();
    public Color groupColor;

    public ArrayList<Sparkle> starterTrail;

    public Firework(Window myPanel) {
        this.myPanel = myPanel;
        this.exploded = false;
        this.groupColor = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
        sparkles = new ArrayList<Sparkle>();
        starterSparkle = new Sparkle(this, true);
        starterTrail = new ArrayList<Sparkle>();
        sparkles.add(starterSparkle);
        for(int i = 0; i < myPanel.SPARKLES_PER_FIREWORK; i++) {
            sparkles.add(new Sparkle(this,false));
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for(Sparkle s : sparkles) {
            s.draw(g);
        }
        if(!exploded) {
            for(int alpha = 255, i = 0; alpha >= 5; alpha-=starterSparkle.ySpeed*10, i++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(starterSparkle.myColor.getRed(), starterSparkle.myColor.getGreen(), 
                    starterSparkle.myColor.getBlue(), alpha));
                g.fillRect((int) starterSparkle.x, (int) (starterSparkle.y + (starterSparkle.ySpeed * i)), 
                    (int) this.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS, (int) this.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS);
            }
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        for(Sparkle s : sparkles) {
            s.move();
        }
        if(sparkles.get(0).ySpeed < 0.5F) {
            explode();
        }
    }

    public void explode() {
        int counter = 0;
        if(!exploded) {
            for(Sparkle s : sparkles) {
                s.show = true;
                //System.out.println(counter++);
                if(rand.nextInt(2) == 1) {
                    s.shuffle(true);
                    System.out.println("im individual!");
                } else {
                    s.shuffle(false); 
                    System.out.println("im not individual!");
                }
            }
            this.exploded = true;
            System.out.println("exploded!");
        }
        if(sparkles.get(0).lifespan < 1) {
            expired = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Sparkle class:

```java
package Firework;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sparkle {

    public Random randomizer;
    public float x,y;
    public int lifespan;
    public static float gravity = 0.95F;
    public float ySpeed;
    public float xSpeed;
    public Color myColor;
    public boolean show;
    public Firework myFirework;
    public static int counter = 0;

    public Sparkle(Firework myFirework, boolean show) {
        this.randomizer = new Random();
        this.lifespan = 255;
        this.myFirework = myFirework;
        this.show = show;
        this.myColor = Color.WHITE;
        this.xSpeed = 0F;
        if(show) {
            this.y = myFirework.myPanel.getHeight();
            this.x = randomizer.nextInt(myFirework.myPanel.getWidth());
            this.ySpeed = (randomizer.nextFloat()*30) + 15F;
        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if(show) {
            g.setColor(myColor);
            g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, (int) myFirework.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS, (int) myFirework.myPanel.SPARKLESIZE_PIXELS);
            Color temp = myColor;
            myColor = new Color(temp.getRed(), temp.getGreen(), temp.getBlue(), lifespan);
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        this.y -= this.ySpeed;
        this.x += this.xSpeed; 
        this.xSpeed *= this.gravity;
        this.ySpeed *= this.gravity;
        if(myFirework.exploded) {
            lifespan = (int) ( (float) lifespan * 0.98F );
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(boolean isIndividual) {

        this.myColor = myFirework.groupColor;
        if(isIndividual) {
            this.myColor = new Color(randomizer.nextInt(255), randomizer.nextInt(255), randomizer.nextInt(255));

        }     
        float maxOverall = randomizer.nextInt(4);
        this.x = this.myFirework.starterSparkle.x;
        this.y = this.myFirework.starterSparkle.y;
        this.ySpeed = (randomizer.nextFloat()*4F) - 2F;
        this.xSpeed = maxOverall - Math.abs(ySpeed);
        if(randomizer.nextInt(2) == 1) {
            //System.out.println("turned vorzeichen");
            xSpeed -= (2*xSpeed);
            //System.out.println(xSpeed);
        } 
        //this.xSpeed = (randomizer.nextFloat()*50F) - 25F;
    }

}
```

It would be great if you could give me some advice, you don't need to write code it would also help me if you just give me some ideas.

And yea I know everything is public and shit but I just wanted to write a quick firework program thats all :)

I can give you the whole code too if you want to test ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a different class for the points in the sparkle's trail? Call each point a `SparkleTrail`, have them be stationary and let them draw themselves with slowly-decreasing opacity, and finally make them vanish (= remove it from the `draw()` loop) once their opacity reaches 0.

Proposed changes:

- new `SparkleTrail` class, has two coordinates, an initial opacity of, say, 0.5. Paints itself when you call its `draw` method. Has a `slowlyVanish` method that decreases opacity by 0.01 whenever you call it, which you will do each 1/50th of a second (or whatever your framerate is), therefore slowly vanishing after aprox. 1 second.
- create them every 10 frames of moving your `Sparkle`, adding them with the current sparkle's position to a `trail` arraylist. This will make the trail brighter when the sparkle moves slow, and space it apart when it moves very fast.
- call `draw` on all `SparkleTrail` instances in the `trail` arraylist whenever you redraw everything. Make sure to call their `slowlyVanish` method, and when opacity reaches zero, remove them from the `trail`.